# Alternatives for windows phone emulator in Non-slat machines

Tags: emulation, windows-10

Post installing Windows 10 , and then Visual studio 2015 pro, I found , to my disappointment , that my laptop model G480lenovo doesn't support Hardware virtualization. In fact there is no entry for "CPU" in my BIOS configuration section.
So then , there is no phone emulators which I could use available in my VS
What are the alternatives here for the emulators that I could use, for testing universal windows applications?
Any pointers here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cannot run Hyper-V on your machine, you need to test it directly with device.

**But**...I think it's better to double confirm if the CPU doesn't support SLAT. There is tools called Coreinfo. And you can download it from [windows sysinternals](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/cc835722.aspx).

After you download it and extract to a folder(for example: c:\coreinfo). Open command prompt as administrator and navigate to the folder(cd c:\coreinfo), then run coreinfo.exe -v (as below image shows). You can see it is supported on my end.

[image]

I did a quick research and found the G480 Lenovo uses i5-3210M or i3-2370M. And found the following specifications on intel official website which indicates both CPU support the EPT(Extended Page Tables) which is SLAT.

http://ark.intel.com/products/67355/Intel-Core-i5-3210M-Processor-3M-Cache-up-to-3_10-GHz-rPGA

http://ark.intel.com/products/53442/Intel-Core-i3-2370M-Processor-3M-Cache-2_40-GHz

If you cannot find the options in BIOS, I think you need to contact your vendor to help you and maybe you need to update your BIOS firmware.

Comment: Wow , thanks a ton Alan! i don't think i could have a more definitive answer!! As it turns out , coreinfo indicated that my processor does indeed support Hyper-V, i probably have to flash the BIOS firmware.